# i3wm | Open application on startup if not in weekend

Tags: configuration, startup, i3

I'm trying to configure i3 so that an application is opened only on working days.
I understand that `exec` can be used to launch apps on startup as in
`exec --no-startup-id telegram-desktop`
However after reading and trying differents things I'm not getting how to use `exec` correctly.

For the moment I have this (which does not work):
`exec --no-startup-id 'test $(date +%u) -lt 6 && slack'`

The command itself works, since the following binding works:
`bindsym $mod+i exec "test $(date +%u) -lt 6 && slack"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
exec --no-startup-id test $(date +%u) -lt 6 && slack
```

or

```
exec --no-startup-id "test $(date +%u) -lt 6 && slack"
```

#### Explanation

*i3* only uses double quotes (`"`) for quoting and does not handle single quotes (`'`) in any way. This means that the whole string `'test $(date +%u) -lt 6 && slack'` - including the quotes - gets passed to `/bin/sh` for execution. That means `/bin/sh` will look for a command with the name `test $(date +%u) -lt 6 && slack` instead of parsing it into a command line that start with the command `test`.